# Total War: Rome 2 using llvmpipe instead of nvidia card

Tags: nvidia

I am a new Linux user, and have been running into problems with my nvidia card. Most of which, I have been able to solve by reinstalling the drivers. However, I recently downloaded Total War: Rome 2, and was met with 2-10FPS in the menu screen. I initially thought it was a cache problem, since the seemed to have been the problem for other games in the past, however, upon clicking the advanced tab in the graphics settings for the game, I noticed that the card it was using is llvmpipe, instead of my GTX 1080ti.

I have searched the internet for a solution to this, and have come up with nothing. when issuing the command `glxinfo | grep "OpenGL renderer"` I get the output `OpenGL renderer string: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080/PCIe/SSE2`

Among other grep commands and config files to see if my 1080 is recognized, which it is. I have no idea what would be the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Total War: Rome 2 is Windows only software. Although not explicitly mentioned - and it definitively should have been - it must be run with Wine or some variant like Steam's Proton (hopefully).

The Steam version is actually the only one so far with posted [results at WineHQ](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=28925), where it is mentioned:

> **What does not [work]**
>
> OpenGL renderer not enabled by default.
>
> **Workarounds**
>
> Forced OpenGL renderer by settting *gfx_device_type* to *2* in *drive_c/users//Application Data/The Creative Assembly/Rome2/scripts/preferences.script.txt*

Also of notice are the **Additional Comments**:

> Fullscreen doesn't work properly with OpenGL renderer enabled.
>
> Game sometimes doesn't start on the first try.

Overall the game gets a "Silver" rating. Most users say that anything below "Gold" is almost always a waste of time. You decide.

Comment: Thanks for your response, and this is useful information, however, does not answer my question. The game is recognizing my graphics card as llvmpipe, instead of my gtx 1080ti. From what I have read, this is a virtual graphics card, that is a workaround. Is there not any way to force a program to use my graphics card, and/or give me a readout as to why it is not using it?

Comment: Have you tried it? Or are just assuming? No, it's not a virtual graphics card, at all. LLVM means a software rendering that happens exactly because "OpenGL renderer not enabled by default", according to the person who posted this test.

Comment: BTW, the path mentioned isn't the most readable or correct one but you should find it under ~./.wine . If using Files to navigate you may need to enable hidden files/folders (CTRL+H)